# After sending to a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a Sendable data extension where I am manually importing the new subscribers.

Now, after an email is sent to this DE, all these subscribers also get loaded into All Subscribers database automatically. But only 'EmailAddress' and 'SubscriberKey' is populated in All Subscribers. Other attributes like First Name, Last Name stay blank.

Is there a way to populate all the fields automatically from DE to All Subscribers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there isn't a way to set the Attributes automatically from a Data Extension send.

You could simply import your source file into All Subscribers...which begs the question, why not just send to a List?

Comment: Thanks Adam! To answer your question - I want to trigger the journey builder interaction as soon as data arrives in a DE.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't map all fields.

1. In the Field section of the extension you have to create the fields and relationships.
2. Create an Import Activity in which you map the source fields to the extension fields.

Comment: Hello Fred, I think I didn't make my problem clear enough. I have edited my question above.